# How do I clean up in Dispose if I can't call UIKit from another thread?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uikit, dispose, ui-thread

Most of my UIKit `Dispose` overrides do something with other views before they get destroyed:

```
protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    if (ScrollView != null) {
        ScrollView.RemoveObserver (this, new NSString ("contentOffset"));
        ScrollView.RemoveObserver (this, new NSString ("contentInset"));
        ScrollView = null;
    }

    base.Dispose (disposing);
}
```

I just recently realized that `Dispose` will run on finalizer thread if `disposing` is `false`.
In this case `ScrollView.RemoveObserver` will be called from non-UI thread which is Bad.

What's the safe way to do UIKit-related cleanup in `Dispose`?

Comment: Just checking - `will run on finalizer thread if disposing is true` should read `false`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If disposing is `false`, then you would probably be better off not calling that code.

```
protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (ScrollView != null) {
            ScrollView.RemoveObserver (this, new NSString ("contentOffset"));
            ScrollView.RemoveObserver (this, new NSString ("contentInset"));
            ScrollView = null;
        }
    }
    base.Dispose (disposing);
}
```

As a more general answer to your question - assuming this code is in a UIViewController - it might be better to attach/detach these observers inside ViewDidAppear, ViewDidDisappear - then you can avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is inside a custom view, I assume I could move this to `RemoveFromSuperview` then.

Answer (score 4):

Adam Kemp posted a great explanation in a [mirror thread on Xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1134/how-do-i-clean-up-in-dispose-if-i-cant-call-uikit-from-another-thread).

> Only if `disposing` is `true` should you do any of that work. If it's
>   `false` then you're being called from a finalizer and so it's not safe
>   to access that other object. The only things you should access in that
>   case would be any unmanaged resources (like an `IntPtr` which stores a
>   native allocation you need to free or a native thread you need to
>   kill).
>
> This obviously brings up the question of when to do the work you're
>   currently doing there. If you're in a view controller then you could
>   use a method like `WillDisappear`. If you are in a view then you could
>   just use `WillMoveToWindow` (which gets called with null as the window
>   if you are being removed from the window).

[Another important bit](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/3871/#Comment_3871) regarding `ReleaseDesignerOutlets`:

> You can't call `ReleaseDesignerOutlets` when called from a finalizer
>   either. Remember, it is not safe to look at any other managed objects
>   referenced by your object in your finalizer. Those objects may no
>   longer exist.
>
> This is safe to skip because each of those other objects already has a
>   similar finalizer. If you never get around to calling `Dispose()` on
>   them then they will have their finalizers called from the finalizer
>   thread, and in that case their own finalizer will call their own
>   `Dispose(bool)` with a false, which means "you're being called from a
>   finalizer". Since the native object is an unmanaged resource (just an
>   `IntPtr`) it is safe for their `Dispose(bool)` method to release the
>   reference to those native resources to allow those native objects to
>   leave memory.
>
> You can actually use the assembly browser to look at what `NSObject`'s
>   `Finalize` and `Dispose(bool)` methods do to verify what I just described.
>   Whatever you do, never access your managed resources from within a
>   finalizer, which means never access them from `Dispose(bool)` when the
>   disposing argument is false.

Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use

```
InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {....})
```

to kill the UIKit stuff? Not 100% sure it'd do what you want, but thats the normal way of doing UIKit stuff when you might be on / are on a different thread.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be safe though.